# should extern variables be scrutinized more than other variables when used with functions that can result in buffer overflows?

Tags: c++, extern, buffer-overflow

I was just wondering if treating an extern variable as the source buffer and passing it as an argument to strcpy() or any other function that can result in a buffer overflow is as unsafe and likely to result in buffer overflows as passing it an argument that came from an fgets() function with a specified limit higher than the size of the buffer.

Should special care be used with these extern variables or should they be treated no differently than any other variable?

Comment: What's unsafe about fgets()?  It limits buffer length and guarantees a null terminator before the end of that specified length...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extern` only defines the **linkage** of an variable it does not change the variable in any other way.

> **Whether it is safe?**

It is as safe/Unsafe as any other variable, the variable being declared `extern` has no bearing.
Using `strcpy` is as such Unsafe and may cause buffer overflows.
In C++ better option is to use `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you control the use of the variable completely, then it would be as "safe" as any other "global" or even local variable for that matter. If you have no control over the use of the variable and how it is created (e.g., someone else provides the module you are linking to) and you do not know their coding practices, then it would probably be wise to treat the variable with more than the usual skepticism.

In general, though, as a matter of course it would be better to use one of the "safe" strcpy functions that accepts the target buffer length even if you completely control the use of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Passing any argument to `strcpy` is unsafe and likely to result in buffer overflows. `extern` has no bearing on this fact. The wise man uses `std::string` (or a Unicode-supporting variant), and never `char*` or `strcpy` or any of those.

Comment: "extern variable as the source buffer". Looks like this extern is not destination.

Comment: Has no bearing on what I said.